# How to create a routing loop?

Tags: routing, loop

Let's say I have two or three routers and I want the packets sent between them NOT to reach their destination but to "loop" between the routers until TTL runs out." I need to do this in a network simulator called Filius but info about how would this happen in reality or in other network simulator should also help.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, this question comes across sounding suspiciously like a homework question, which is off topic here. If it is not school work, please edit your question to provide more context about why you are asking and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 4):

If this was your setup:

```
Host A ---- Router B ---- Router C ---- Router D ---- Host E
```

Tell Router B that the network for Host E exists at Router C.
Tell Router C that the network for Host E exists at Router B.

A packet from Host A to Host E will then get caught in a routing loop between Routers B and C.

Comment: *Routers B and C (edits must be at least 6 characters? pffft)

Comment: @thorr18 Oops. Fixed it. Good catch. Thanks.